# Node.JS interpreter for Sublime Text issue

Tags: javascript, sublimetext

I just installed Node.js to run my JS code in Sublime Text. I can create a function, run it and the output is correct, however, if I use something like var num = prompt(); , I get the following error:

```
num = prompt();
      ^
ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/laptop/Google Drive/Development:Programming/Learning_Javascript/Eloquent_Javascript_Book/test.JS:2:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: Node.js doesn't define a `prompt()` function. The function is [defined by the HTML5 standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.prompt) and is meant for use within browsers. Try looking into [`readline`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) for a command-line equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use `readline()` (as suggest by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415183/node-js-interpreter-for-sublime-text-issue#comment43274440_27415183)), Sublime does not allow for interactive input, regardless of language - Python's `input()` or `raw_input()`, Ruby's `gets`, `scanf` and colleagues in C/C++, etc. To run your program interactively, you'll either need to use a build system that runs it through a shell, or use [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) and the `Evaluate in REPL` commands.